# jekyll how to read from markdown content

Tags: jekyll

I wonder can I use jekyll to read the content of a markdown line by line and generate a timeline page?

Basically, I want to achieve something like [this](https://cawal.github.io/markdown/2017/10/13/timeline_in_markdown.html). I assume I need to make a HTML file like `timeline.html`, and then in the markdown title has a thing like `layout: timeline`.

I already find some codes to create this timeline view. Like below

```
<div id="archives" class="pl-xl-3">
 <div class="year lead">2022</div>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>
      <span class="date day">25</span>
      <span class="date month small text-muted ml-1">Dec</span>
      <a> My first news</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

But what I want is a way to automatically replace the '25', 'Dec', and 'My first news' with the content in my markdown file.

Any hint about how to access the markdown content in this HTML file is appreciated!

Comment: Your link contains instructions, did you follow them? You won't have to write any HTML yourself.

Comment: Yes, but the file in the link is 404. And I think even with the scss file, I still need a html file? I thought scsss file is just like a css file.

Comment: Oh, I see. The SCSS gets converted to CSS by Jekyll. That CSS provides a class `timeline-md`, which can be applied to a block in Markdown using the `{: .timeline-md}` syntax. The CSS makes a table look like a timeline in the generated HTML, but the input is only Markdown and the correct style file. Now, since the SCSS is gone, you could just copy the entire [generated CSS file](https://cawal.github.io/css/main.css), or you could ask the author if they could provide that SCSS file for you.